# Placement of 'Immediately' in sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, adverb-placement, adjective-order

- "That will be immediately taken care by user"
- "That will immediately be taken care by user"
- "That will be taken care of, immediately"

Which one is correct?

Comment: The verb is **to take care of {something}**. That is, to handle it, to address it, to see that something is done in respect to it.

Comment: Assuming you add the "of" (as @Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions), any of those would work fine. There is no "one" that is correct.

Comment: The first two versions should end with _taken care of by the user_ instead of _...by user_.

Answer (score 1):

All three of the sentences make perfect sense, however the message that you are conveying is slightly different in each case.

- That will be immediately taken care of by (**the**) user

and

- That will immediately be taken car of by (**the**) user

convey the same message: the issue will be taken care of by the user now or soon.

- That will be taken care of by (**the**) user, immediately.

In this case, there is more emphasis on the "immediately", so it suggests that the person before has complained about something and there is haste to sort it out. It suggests reassurance. This issue in this case will be sorted out right now, whereas the other two phrases imply now or in the near future but there is less haste.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the placement of "immediately" in the sentence, all three variants are correct.

However, the verb is: "to take care **of**" and therefore, the first two sentences need a small update (notice the extra "of"):

> - "That will be immediately taken care **of** by user"
> - "That will immediately be taken care **of** by user"